# How can I extract a centered window from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(0,21,1)
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
```

Now suppose that I want to pick a window of length `N`, where `2 < N <= a.shape[0]`, such that the window is "centered" around one of the elements of the array `a`. For example, if I want to center a window of length `N = 5` around the element `10` in array `a`, then this window would be:

```py
>>> idx = 10 # index of the array element 10
>>> N = 5 # window size
>>> a[idx - N//2:idx + N//2 + 1]
array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

This method generalizes well for windows that are not near the edges of the array, but I can't make it work otherwise. For example, if I want to extract a window of length `N = 7` around the element `2` in `a`, then what I get is:

```py
>>> idx = 2
>>> N = 7
>>> a[idx - N//2:idx + N//2 + 1]
array([], dtype=int32)
```

However what I want is:

```py
>>> a[0:7]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

How can I generalize this method for windows near the edges of `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66694792/13809128), here is what worked:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,21,1)
idx = 5 # desired element index
N = 7 # window length

if N % 2: # if window length is odd
    step = N // 2
else: # if window length is even
    step = int(N/2 - 1)

# make sure starting index is between 0 and a.shape[0] - N
start = min(max(idx-step,0),a.shape[0] - N)
window = a[start:start + N]
```

Comment: I think the algorithm could be just `step = (N - 1) // 2`, which will produce the same result. Try `all([(lambda N: N // 2 if N % 2 else int(N/2 - 1))(N) == (N - 1) // 2 for N in range(100)])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
idx = 2
start = min(idx - N//2, 0)
a[start:start + N]
```

Note that this is not centered at `idx=2`.

Comment: I tried `idx = 0` and it worked using `max` instead of `min`. Also, this doesn't work for `idx > 18`, since `a[start:start + N]` returns a window with length less than `N`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take) and wrap if a small array, more readable in one line:

```py
>>>a.take(range(idx - N//2, idx + N//2 + 1), mode="wrap")
array([20,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5])
```

If it is big, performance might be an issue, you can use a view, see:
[Numpy subarrays and relative indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75069904/numpy-subarrays-and-relative-indexing?noredirect=1#comment132485740_75069904).